# .toggleClass not working, no idea why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am trying to get a div box to expand when clicked, and go back to normal size when clicked again. Seems simple enough, but I can not get it to work no matter what I try. I have no idea what could be going wrong as the part of the code where the error is most likely to be occurring is not very long. Thanks for your time!
https://jsfiddle.net/uL1r08am/

```
<div id='panelHolder'>
  <div id='panel1' class='panels'></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.panels {
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid silver;
  transition:transform 1.5s;
}

.panels:hover {
  transform:skewY(3deg);
}

#panel1.clicked{
  width:460;
  height:290;
}
```

---

```
$('#panel1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});

$(document).ready(main)
```

Comment: it's working , what you want from it ?

Comment: If you inspect the elements in your fiddle, the 'clicked' class IS toggling...

Comment: The javascript is working fine, your CSS syntax is faulty so it's not doing anything. Change `width:460;` to `width:460px;` Also, `$(document).ready(main)` isn't doing anything because `main` is undefined

Comment: I will edit and phrase it better, I meant that it is not expanding like I said in my description

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `px`

Change :

```
#panel1.clicked{
  width:460;
  height:290;
}
```

To :

```
#panel1.clicked{
  width:460px;
  height:290px;
}
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .panels {
                  position:relative;
                  border:2px solid silver;
                  transition:transform 1.5s;
                }

            .panels:hover {
              transform:skewY(3deg);
            }

        #panel1.clicked{
          width:460px;
          height:290px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id='panelHolder'>
            <div id='panel1' class='panels'>DIV</div>
        </div>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#panel1').on('click', function() {  
                $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The size is not changing, because you are missing `px` on your width and height values. The toggle itself is working fine.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uL1r08am/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your javascript code inside document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#panel1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
})
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not the problem here. `width: 460; height: 290;` is meaningless when the numbers come without units. (he forgot to say that the sizes were in px)

Answer (score 0):

You can try addClass and removeClass

```
$('#panel1').click(function() {
  if ($('#panel1').hasClass('clicked'))
     $('#panel1').removeClass('clicked');
  else
     $('#panel1').addClass('clicked');
});
```